# Unable to install Debian

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I am trying to install Debian from a Live USB. I got my ISO image from [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.4.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/), and the one I got is "Debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-xfce+nonfree.iso".

I used [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to create the live USB.

I rebooted my computer and fired up the live USB. I first noticed something was off when I was in the installer and clicked the option "Debian GNU/Linux Live (kernel 4.19.0-9-amd64)", and the screen freezes up for a moment then I get these error messages:

```
Unable to bind the codec
failed to load firmware chunk
iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
could not load the [0] uCode section
Failed to start INIT uCode -110
Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel
Failed to run INIT ucode -110
```

After this I get a black screen with just one white dash and am forced to reboot my computer. Well I thought OK, that's fine; I'll just use the graphical installer. I went through the process, and I was able to successfully install. I chose the option to use entire disk for partitioning by the way. When I booted up my computer at this point I was put at the Debian home screen where I have three options being "Debian GNU/Linux", "Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux", and "System setup." When I click the first option I get end up with a screen that has the exact same error messages that I listed prior.

My computer is a [System 76 Darter Pro](https://system76.com/laptops/darter).

I tried using the graphical installer three different times but the last time has made it so when I turn on my computer I just get a grey screen. I am still able to go to the firmware boot and fire up the live USB.

All I have at this point is the live USB stick and a MacBook. What are my options? Is it possible to make a bootable USB from my Mac? The USB currently is not readable on my Mac, and this is the only USB I have at the moment.

Edit: I no longer have access to the Live USB as I have gone ahead and tried to get a new ISO file from my Mac and erased it.

Edit2: I was able to successfully install Xubuntu, by download [Xubuntu's ISO](http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/xubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso) file and [checking for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu), then making a [LiveUSB with Etcher](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos) and [installing](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop) it.

Comment: Just for a test, try a different image from a different distro, this way:  Download Xubuntu's ISO file at http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/ or a different 'flavour' https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions a Mac https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos. Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks for the links

Comment: @K7AAY I was able to successfully install Xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The test, of creating a Xubuntu LiveUSB following Ubuntu's steps outlined in the question  shows the USB flash drive is not faulty, and your copy of *Etcher* is OK.

That leaves the downloaded ISO file as the likely cause; either a faulty download, a one-time defect in creating the Debian LiveUSB, or choosing the wrong options during its  installation.

Please redownload the Debian ISO and verify it per https://www.debian.org/CD/verify then perform another installation from the LiveUSB you create with Etcher.

Comment: I continue to be unable to install Debian. I have verified two different CD's, and have attempted to install multiple different desktop environments. I have now failed with over 10 versions of Debian (all 10.4 though). I watched an installation tutorial by somebody using a System 76 laptop, though I do not know what laptop version he has, and he was installing Debian 10.0. I have tried to download versions that do not include non-free software. I have tried using UNetBootin instead of Etcher. The issue that I have is the exact same each time, matching the one outlined in this post.

Comment: Then, report as bug to Debian team, and reach out to System76 to ask them about it.

Comment: Will do. Im going to the store to purchase a different USB. Quite strange.